# Creating a bat file that runs a certain command on cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ping

So normally I can type this into the `cmd` window `ping 216.52.241.254 -t` and it tells me my ping to a certain server. How can I create a `.bat` file that automatically opens the `cmd` window and types it in so that I don't have to write it out every single time. I tried just putting in `ping 216.52.241.254 -t` and it just spams it over and over again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way of doing this (potentially a lot easier for you) would be to create a shortcut:

1. Right Click in windows explorer and hover over "`New`"
2. Select "`Shortcut`"
3. A dialogue will pop-up. Enter the command you wish to utilize: `ping 216.52.241.254 -t`
4. Click Next and name the file.
5. Now whenever you open the shortcut, it will execute the command.

The advantage of this method over the other is its simpler and allows you to pin it to the Starmenu or Taskbar.

Mona.

Answer (score 3):

It spammed it over and over because you called the batch file `ping` so it was launching itself.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

```
@echo off
ping 216.52.241.254 -t
Echo.
pause
```

1. Open Notepad
2. Copy and paste this in.
3. Save as a `.bat` file, ensuring that you select "`all files`" option
4. Run the batch file any time you want to check your ping.

Done!

Answer (score 1):

type the following:

```
cd\ 
ping -t 216.52.241.254
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have keep the file name as '**ping.bat**'.
Rename it to something else and it will definitely work. 
ex : ping1.bat, something.bat etc., anything else but ping.

Answer (score 0):

It spams it again and again because you used -t which "Pings the specified host until stopped." if you lose the -t it won't do that. Type Ping /? to look through all the options available when using ping and select what is appropriate for what you want it to do.